# Is it a problem that I see daylight through my shed's soffit?

Tags: framing, roof, roofing, soffit

First and foremost - please excuse my ignorance and improper use of terminology.

I have a free standing garage with a mono-pitched / shed style roof:

[image]

The garage is unfinished inside and I noticed that during the day there is daylight shining through all along the eave / soffit portion (I think that's what it's called. Basically where the high wall meets the top of the roof). I have also noticed a little bit of water damage on the high wall (which may be just do to the older roof) and a lot of / squirrel droppings.

**From inside:**
[image: https://i.imgur.com/o3kJCPP.jpg]
[image]
[image]

**From outside:**
[image: https://i.imgur.com/TovjjyW.jpg]
[image]

-Are these gaps normal?

-Should they be sealed up?

-If so - how do I go about doing this? Expanding foam seems like it would make a mess as it expands to the outside.

-I do plan on finishing the inside of the garage at some point - so while I'm up there, would I need to install vents in the soffit?

Comment: I can't see your soffit situation in those underexposed photos, but soffit isn't a requirement. It's for aesthetic reasons and pest prevention. Even with soffit there's likely to be the occasional light leak. Post better photos or an explanation of what's there if you want more help.

Comment: @isherwood thank you for the response! Even with a better photo it's tough to see the gaps outside the structure. If you look at my photos of the inside - you can see the light shining through. Right now the soffit is just a solid board.

Answer (score 1):

My shed has (better-sheltered) gaps.  I believe my shed's gaps are on purpose, to enable air circulation.  This prevents mold and mildew problems in the unheated space.

I am surprised that your shed has fiberglass insulation in the walls, but not in the ceiling.  With no heat, and so many thermal bridges and air gaps, I would be surprised if the insulation noticeably affects the temperature inside the shed.

Comment: I think the insulation was just leftover from another project and the previous owner just put it up there, because not all of the walls have insulation.